# Highcharts setData not working with php,json on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am learning highcharts and got stuck in the scenario of updating the charts with new data from the php,json . I have verified that the new data is in the correct JSON format by creating a separate graph with the data.

Below is my code :

```
var my_chart;

    var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 75,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Man Weeks Allocation Region Wise',
        x: -20 //center
    },
     plotOptions: {
            column: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'True that',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Count'
        },
        gridLineColor: '#197F07',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineWidth:1,
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
        this.x +': '+ this.y;
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

    series: []
    }


 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("getData.php", function(json) {
        console.log(json[0]);
        console.log(json[1]);
    options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
    options.series[0] = json[1];
    my_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
 });


$("#button1" ).click(function() {
    $.getJSON("getNewData.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[1]);       
        my_chart.series[0].setData(data[1]);
        my_chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(data[0]['data']);
    });
});
```

When i click the button , it prints the correct data on the console , but the graph is not updated , earlier graph data is also vanished..

But the following is working if I hard code the data:

```
$("#button1" ).click(function() {
    $.getJSON("getNewData.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[1]);   
        my_chart.series[0].setData([1,2,3,4,5]);
        my_chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['A','B','C','D','E']);
    });
});
```

Is there something which i am missing to dynamically change the data ?

I can assure that JSON data is in the correct format as the chart is plotting if i use the same in the document ready function instead of button click function.

Comment: If you hardcode data and it works and then it doesnt work with the json then it must be something with the json - make sure that your data array from json is an array of numbers - not an array of strings

Comment: Without seeing the output of your returned JSON, it's hard to say much...

Comment: Here is the json data :

[{"name":"city","data":["Multiple Cities","IrvineDallas","Seattle","Irvine","Brazil","New Jersey","Moscow","Atlanta","Johannesburg","Dallas","Baltimore","India","Syracause","New York","Argentina","Miami","Chicago","USA","Thailand"]},{"name":"Value","data":[12.5,6,3.3,6.3,8.6,4.9,3.8,3.3,4.8,4.8,3.7,14.3,1.8,5.7,3.8,1.8,4,2.8,3.8]}]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the xAxis.categories and series in options and creating the chart again is working fine.

```
$("#city" ).click(function() {
    $.getJSON("getNewData.php", function(data) {
        console.log(data[0]);
        console.log(data[1]);
        options.xAxis.categories = data[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = data[1];
        my_chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

Is there any other way to update the chart using setData and setCategories ?